# Another UI for Dask except bokeh

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Isn't there another Dask UI except for bokeh?

I have a problem with bokeh, as it is not showing the graph and UI when running in an ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Dask's dashboard uses Bokeh.  The problem here is probably not with Bokeh, but with some networking policy that is running on your deployment.  There is nothing stopping Bokeh from working with EC2.